# Access database encoding cp1250 in Talend

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, encoding, talend

I have problem with encoding in Talend when reading Access (.mdb) file. All day I'm stuck and looking for the solution.

In Access one column has characters contain(½,¼,¾).
In that column, data is like 3¾. Symbols are part of the CP1250 encoding page.

Problem is when I am reading the Access file with tAccessInput transformation. All I got as the result is like 3?. Question mark stands for ¾ simbol.

I am looking for the additional parameter for the Access JDBC connection. I have tried many combinations with values like "encodind=cp1250", didn't work.

I have already write java custom class that parses string value like 4¾, 2½ into the decimal.

Screen shot of the Talend job: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/id1poblmcfdrsd9/PrtScr.jpg

Thanks for any help.

Josip

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `"charSet=windows-1250"` in the Additional JDBC Parameters field in the Advanced Settings tab.